# multithread server socket with delphi xe5 for android

Tags: android, delphi, serversocket

how can i make multithread socket with events (onread, onconnect,...) for ;

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.StdCtrls,
  androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes, FMX.Layouts, FMX.Memo, IdBaseComponent, IdThreadComponent,
  Android.Soket;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    th: TIdThreadComponent;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure thRun(Sender: TIdThreadComponent);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  serversoket:JServerSoket;
  client:JSoket;
  output:JoutStream;
  input :JinStream;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  try
    serversoket:=TJServerSoket.JavaClass.init(8090);
    memo1.Lines.Add('listen, only 1 client');
  except
    on E:Exception do memo1.Lines.Add('Cant open port: '+E.Message);

  end;
  th.Active:=true;
  th.Start;
end;

procedure TForm1.thRun(Sender: TIdThreadComponent);
var msg:string;
begin
  client  :=serversoket.accept;
  if client.isConnected then
  begin
    if client.getInputStream.available>-1 then
    begin
      input:=tjinstream.JavaClass.init(client.getInputStream);
      output:=tJoutStream.JavaClass.init(client.getOutputStream)  ;
    end;
    while true do
     begin
      msg:=jstringtostring(input.readline);
      memo1.Lines.Add('Read: '+ msg );
      output.writeUTF(stringtojstring('msg: '+msg ) );
      memo1.Lines.Add('Write!' );
      output.flush;
     end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

android server socket api for delphi ( :P ) ;

```
unit Android.Soket;

interface

uses  Androidapi.JNIBridge, Androidapi.Jni,  androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes, androidapi.JNI.Net,
      Androidapi.JNI.Os, FMX.Helpers.Android, Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText,System.SysUtils,
      System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,FMX.Memo;


type

  ////////////////////////////soket/////////////////////////////


  [javaSignature('java/net/InetAddress')]
  JAdres=interface(JObject)
  ['{7A525333-38BC-4D2A-8160-D164D1CAA30E}']
    function getHostName:Jstring;cdecl;
    property Host:Jstring read getHostName;
  end;

  JAdresClass=interface(JObjectClass)
  ['{B34C47C9-7FC8-4120-B087-60F517A9323D}']
  end;
  TJAdres = class(TJavaGenericImport<JAdresClass, JAdres>) end;


 ////////////////out buffer////////////////////


  [javaSignature('java/io/OutputStream')]
  Jout=interface(jobject)
    ['{AC9EEC99-FF3A-46E4-AFC3-C4D3309D8C8E}']
  end;
  JoutClass = interface(JObjectClass)
    ['{46FBBEEE-22C7-45EA-BED3-A41BED01E500}']
    end;
  TJout = class(TJavaGenericImport<JoutClass, Jout>) end;

  [javaSignature('java/io/DataOutputStream')]
  JoutStream=interface(jobject)
    ['{A6421CC3-B76C-4124-AB2E-AEE0C4749E71}']
    procedure write(buffer:TJavaArray<byte>;offset,count:integer);cdecl;overload;
    procedure write(buffer:TJavaArray<byte>);cdecl;overload;
    procedure write(buffer:byte);cdecl;overload;
    procedure writeChars(str:jstring);cdecl;
    procedure writeUTF(str:jstring);cdecl;
    procedure close;cdecl;
    procedure flush;cdecl;
  end;
  JoutStreamClass = interface(JObjectClass)
    ['{83D69F8F-8833-4EF5-B00D-2EA45F58AC46}']
    function init(obj:Jout):JoutStream; cdecl;overload;//Deprecated
  end;
  TJoutStream = class(TJavaGenericImport<JoutStreamClass, JoutStream>) end;
  ///////////////////////input buffer/////////////////

  [javaSignature('java/io/InputStream')]
  Jin=interface(jobject)
    ['{50F3A57E-7E09-4727-954C-34298755D5ED}']
    function read(buffer:TJavaArray<byte>;offset:integer;count:integer):integer;cdecl;overload;
    function read(buffer:TJavaArray<byte>):integer;cdecl;overload;
    function read():integer;cdecl;overload;
    function available():integer;cdecl;
    procedure close;cdecl;
    procedure reset;cdecl;
  end;
  JinClass = interface(JObjectClass)
    ['{91C1D3F0-30FD-4961-9560-1B9045DBAC3B}']
    function init():Jin; cdecl;overload;//Deprecated
  end;
  TJin = class(TJavaGenericImport<JinClass, Jin>) end;
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  [javaSignature('java/io/DataInputStream')]
  JinStream=interface(jobject)
  ['{839ACAEC-229A-4261-88B4-136173B6FCBF}']
    function available():integer;cdecl;
    function read(buffer:TJavaObjectArray<byte>;offset,count:integer):integer;cdecl;overload;
    function read(buffer:TJavaObjectArray<byte>):integer;cdecl;overload;
    function read():integer;cdecl;overload;
    function readUTF():jstring;cdecl;
    function readLine():jstring;cdecl;
    procedure close;cdecl;
    procedure reset;cdecl;
  end;
  JinStreamClass = interface(JObjectClass)
  ['{27B4071A-5BC8-4594-A701-DBB92DBEE45A}']
    function init(obj:Jin):JinStream; cdecl;overload;
  end;
  TJinStream = class(TJavaGenericImport<JinStreamClass, JinStream>) end;

 ////////////////client socket////////////////////
  [javaSignature('java/net/Socket')]
  JSoket=interface(jobject)
  ['{A8A35BE7-5562-44C5-B599-40B76AD30116}']
    procedure close;cdecl;
    function getOutputStream:Jout;cdecl;
    function getInputStream:Jin;cdecl;
    function isConnected:boolean;cdecl;


  end;

  JSoketClass = interface(JObjectClass)
  ['{E66CE6BA-9E0E-4ED0-A4B7-D683C8AB3597}']
    function init:JSoket;cdecl;
  end;
  TJSoket = class(TJavaGenericImport<JSoketClass, JSoket>) end;

////////////////server socket//////////////////////////

  [javaSignature('java/net/ServerSocket')]
  JServerSoket=interface(jobject)
    ['{56C0FCBB-AE14-4DCE-9E06-9CCC2DB73C5B}']
    function getLocalPort:integer;cdecl;
    procedure bind(localAddr:integer);cdecl;
    procedure close;cdecl;
    function getInetAddress:JAdres;cdecl;
    function accept():JSoket;cdecl;

    property Port: Integer read getLocalPort;
    property iNetAdres: JAdres read getInetAddress;


  end;

  JServerSoketClass = interface(JObjectClass)
  ['{8A35BED3-B8BB-4069-BEB9-2D859F6F74C1}']
    function init(port:integer):JServerSoket;
  end;
  TJServerSoket = class(TJavaGenericImport<JServerSoketClass, JServerSoket>) end;

implementation

end.
```

(these codes can read/write!)
screen image;
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxODt2IJsmR8ZktjNzF5VllzekE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    th: TIdThreadComponent;
    th2: TIdThreadComponent; //for 2. client.
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure thRun(Sender: TIdThreadComponent);
    procedure th2Run(Sender: TIdThreadComponent);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;
......

procedure TForm1.thRun(Sender: TIdThreadComponent);
var msg:string;
  client:JSoket;
  input :JinStream;
  output:JoutStream;
begin
  client  :=serversoket.accept;
  if client.isConnected then
  begin
    if client.getInputStream.available>-1 then
    begin
      input:=tjinstream.JavaClass.init(client.getInputStream);
      output:=tJoutStream.JavaClass.init(client.getOutputStream)  ;
      ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      th2.Active:=true;//2. thread start if 1. client connected!
      th2.Start;
      ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    end;
    while true do
     begin
      msg:=jstringtostring(input.readline);
      memo1.Lines.Add('Read: '+ msg );
      output.writeUTF(stringtojstring('msg: '+msg ) );
      memo1.Lines.Add('Write!' );
      output.flush;
     end;
  end;
end;

......
procedure TForm1.th2Run(Sender: TIdThreadComponent);
var msg:string;
  client:JSoket;
  input :JinStream;
  output:JoutStream;
begin
  client  :=serversoket.accept;
  if client.isConnected then
  begin
    if client.getInputStream.available>-1 then
    begin
      input:=tjinstream.JavaClass.init(client.getInputStream);
      output:=tJoutStream.JavaClass.init(client.getOutputStream)  ;
     //if more client....
    end;
    while true do
     begin
      msg:=jstringtostring(input.readline);
      memo1.Lines.Add('Read2: '+ msg );
      output.writeUTF(stringtojstring('msg2: '+msg ) );
      memo1.Lines.Add('Write2!' );
      output.flush;
     end;
  end;
end;
........
```

screen image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxODt2IJsmR8WVEzTUh3NXJtcjA/edit?usp=sharing
these codes worked. i was try.
i'm waiting answers/comments.
thanks you very much, especially @RemyLebeau

Answer (score 1):

`TIdThreadComponent` is a component of Indy, which has its own `TIdTCPServer` multithreaded component.  You should be using `TIdTCPServer` instead of `TJServerSocket`, which is a Java class wrapped by Delphi's JNI bridge layer, so it does not run "natively" on the CPU.  `TIdTCPServer` does, just like the rest of the Delphi RTL/FMX framework.

```
uses
  ..., IdTCPServer, IdContext;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    IdTCPServer1: TIdTCPServer;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure IdTCPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
    procedure IdTCPServer1Disconnect(AContext: TIdContext);
    procedure IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;
```

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IdTCPServer1.DefaultPort := 8090;
  try
    IdTCPServer1.Active := True;
    memo1.Lines.Add('listening');
  except
    on E: Exception do memo1.Lines.Add('Cant open port: '+E.Message);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  TThread.Synchronize(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      memo1.Lines.Add('connected');
    end
  );
end;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Disconnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  TThread.Synchronize(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      memo1.Lines.Add('disconnected');
    end
  );
end;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  msg: string;
begin
  msg := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn;
  TThread.Synchronize(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      memo1.Lines.Add('Read: '+ msg );
    end
  );
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Write('msg: '+msg, IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
  TThread.Synchronize(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      memo1.Lines.Add('Write!');
    end
  );
end;
```

Comment: i was try these codes. IdTCPServer1Connect,IdTCPServer1Disconnect events stil running. But, IdTCPServer1Execute event is not efective. what should i do at the point?

Comment: Saying that something is "not effective" is not meaningful information about the problem you are having. You need to provide details. Do you have the event assigned? Does the event get triggered? Is the event code hanging, or raising an exception? Please be more specific.

Comment: if you look; here the test app:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxODt2IJsmR8SmlfcjJGcGlvckk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @RemyLebeau Hello Sir, can I use this kind `TThread.Synchronize` approach for `TServerSocket` ?  I am not using Indy.

Comment: @Bianca: If you use `TServerSocket` in non-blocking mode, its events run in the main thread, so synchronize is not needed. But if you use it in thread-blocking mode, it uses a worker thread per client, and you can use synchronize, yes.